# Please help me with this line from Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, meaning

From *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, Gringotts, chapter twenty-six:

> It was now packed inside the beaded bag, which, Harry was impressed to learn,
> Hermione had protected from the Snatchers by the simple **expedient of
> stuffing it down her sock**.

I am unable to understand the word *expedient* and its use in this context. And also, please explain the phrase *stuffing it down her sock*: how did she stuff a bag sewn into her sock?

Plus, try to elaborate as much as possible, as I am new to English it would help a lot.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Consider visiting the [Help Page](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) on how to write a good question. A lookup in a General Reference would be a good start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[to stuff](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=stuff)**, verb 2. a. **To place forcefully into a container or space; thrust**:

*"He stuffed money into the bag."*

[**Expedient**:](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=expedient) (noun)

**2. Something contrived or used to meet an urgent need**:

*"She joined the university football team by the simple expedient of standing on the field and refusing to move off."*

Comment: Typing in the word will give the OP a sense of achievement... https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=expedient

Comment: Kinda like ["stuff it in your pipe and smoke it"...](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stuff-it-them-you-etc)?